# How to make cube A size following cube B size? (boolean for window/door)

Tags: modifiers

ie; I have cube001 for boolean, and cube002 for window frame/leaf, so when I resize high/length of cube002(window mesh) the boolean cube (cube001) is changed too, how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you freeze the scale, it's not like

else
http://take.ms/CTUFw

[image]

[image]

Comment: or use constrain http://take.ms/kElvW